# How to remove scrollBar from rich:extendedDataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using:

```
RichFaces: 3.3.3
JSF: 1.2
```

As said in an official JBoss documentation `<rich:extendedDataTable>` is scrollable. What I need to achieve is to remove scrollbar from the markup rendered by that component? Is it possible to do that in a "native way" without explicitly set of style-class?

Comment: You can change it to regular `rich:dataTable` and setup row count. It is not scrollable.

Comment: @VasilLukach Not possible, I need to use exactly extendedDataTable.

Answer (score 0):

The `extendedDataTable` will break into a scrollbar when it exceeds its default size of `500px` as set by the `height` attribute. Your options are

1. Configure the `height` attribute to a figure that caters to the size of your dataset. This can be tricky and it's generally not advisable
2. Use the [`<rich:dataScroller/>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTableScroller.jsf?c=dataTableScroller&tab=usage) to paginate your data.